# Missing Delete and other options on a report in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have one report in SSRS that is missing the following options that my other reports have available: 'Edit in Report Builder', 'Download', 'Move', and 'Delete'.  The 'Invoice Edit' report is missing the options.  'KCI Invoices Pending' has all the options I would expect the other to have as well.

[image: Broken Report]

[image: Working Report]

Any ideas on what could cause these options to be missing?

Comment: Probably you don't have the appropriate permissions for this report.

Comment: Check the permissions for this report against the user you are logged in as in SSRS

Comment: Hi @niktrs, I should have admin rights for all reports.

Comment: @Kamal, I will double-check all my security settings.  Thanks for these suggestions everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was permission-based.